# Access Custom Pass Volume and its property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a custom pass volume in HDRP and I would like to access and change its properties via script, how do I do this?

In the image given below, how do I enable "Fetch Color Buffer" ?

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition;
 
public class AccessVolume: MonoBehaviour {
 
public CustomPassVolume volume;
 
  void Start() {
 
  }
 
}
```

[CustomVolume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5KRW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// get the first custom pass
var pass = volume.customPasses[0]; 

// only the FullScreenCustomPass class has the property
if (pass is FullScreenCustomPass full) 
    full.fetchColorBuffer = true;
```

Comment: Thanks alot that worked! Also, how do I make "pass" a public variable? Is it public CustomPassVolume pass; ?

Comment: `public FullScreenCustomPass pass` or `public DrawRenderersCustomPass pass` depends on which type of pass you need.